# comparison of variables with different types in python

Tags: python

in my script I get 2 variables Val1 and Val2 from 2 different databases and I have to compare them.

The problem is, that if the type of the variables is different, the variables may representing the same meaning in the database.

So '' (empty string or string contains only blanks) means the same as 0 or 0. or None

Do I have to check all possible combinations of the variable types?
And how do I have to do it to be sure not missing a type?

```
def CompareValues(Val1,Val2,Debug=False):

    if Val1 is None and Val2 is float:
        if Debug:print('none-float')
        if Val2 == 0.        : return True
    if Val1 is None and Val2 is int:
        if Debug:print('none-int')
        if Val2 == 0         : return True
    if Val1 is None and Val2 is str:
        if Debug:print('none-str')
        if Val2.strip() == '': return True
    [...]
    return False
```

Is there a more pythonic way for it?

Comment: `if not Val1 and not Val2:` will check if both values are one of all the falsy types, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
if not Val1:
    #True for [],{},'',0,0.0,False,None, etc..
```

For type checking, you should do `isinstance`

```
In [10]: isinstance(0.0, float)
Out[10]: True

In [11]: isinstance("mystring", str)
Out[11]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that accepts `''` `'  '` `'0'` and `0` and returns zero, in other words coerce the data you are getting to a common datatype.

Then compare the function results.

For example

```
def coerce(n):
    if type(n) is str:
        n = n.strip()
    if not n:
        return 0
    if type(n) is str and n.isdigit():
        return int(n.strip())
    return n

>>> coerce("")
0
>>> coerce("  ")
0
>>> coerce("0")
0
>>> coerce("4")
4
>>> coerce("") == coerce(0)
True
```